# Android: Add listvew items to an array list or any work around to achieve the below?

Tags: java, android, arrays, list, listview

In the below code, where the item’s position and title is getting saved in list_items works fine if list_items and items are ArrayList. For ex;

```
ArrayList.add(ArrayList.get(position));
```

But I am trying to use listview:

```
ArrayList.add(Listview.get(position));
```

Below is my code

```
final Listadapter Adapter =new Listadapter(this,packageList1,packageManager);
items.setAdapter(Adapter);
items.setChoiceMode(apps.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL);
items.setMultiChoiceModeListener(new AbsListView.MultiChoiceModeListener() 
{  
@Override
public void onItemCheckedStateChanged(ActionMode mode, int position, long id, boolean checked)
{        
count = count +1;
mode.setTitle(count + "items selected");    //problem resides in the below line
list_items.add(items.get(position));
}
```

In the above code, on selecting an item from listview I am trying to save it in an Arraylist i.e list_items which could be used in onActionItemClicked method for further action on that respective item.

Any ideas on how to solve or find a workaround to use a listview in the above situation?

Comment: try `list_items.add(Adapter.getItem(position));`

Comment: Thanks Dhaval. I was able to resolve it using get() function